# JS - Replace all strings with local variables inside query

Tags: javascript, regex, sqlite, variables, replace

There is any way to replace all the strings between two @ with the variables that as the same name?

I'm getting all the properties of 'data' object from a http request, so this isn't a local variable, so I don't know the value between the two @, only know the default ones (filtes,search,field)

This is what I'm getting:

*SELECT name, age, address , (name ||  age ||  address) AS search  FROM users WHERE  search LIKE '%lisboa%' AND   name LIKE '%ricardo%' AND  age LIKE '%23%' AND  ndos = **@ndos@** AND nmdos = '**@nmdos@**' AND 1 = 1;*

This is what I need:

*SELECT name, age, address , (name ||  age ||  address) AS search  FROM users WHERE  search LIKE '%lisboa%' AND   name LIKE '%ricardo%' AND  age LIKE '%23%' AND  ndos = **615** AND nmdos = '**Orders**' AND 1 = 1;*

This is my code:

```
var ndos = 615,
    nmdos = "Orders";

var data = {
    search:"lisboa",
    fields:{
        name:"ricardo",
        age:23
    },
    filter:"name, age, address",
    query:"SELECT name, age, address @filter@ FROM users WHERE @search@ @fields@ ndos = @ndos@ AND nmdos = '@nmdos@' AND 1 = 1;"
};

var result = data.query;

var fields = "";

for(var i in data.fields) fields += " " + i + " LIKE '%" + data.fields[i] + "%' AND ";

//check if is searchable
var searchable = (result.indexOf('@filter@') !== -1 && result.indexOf('@search@') !== -1) && data.search;

//build search column
result = result.replace(/@filter@/g,searchable ? ", (" + data.filter.replace(/,/g," || ") + ") AS search " : "");

//search value
result = result.replace(/@search@/g,searchable ? " search LIKE '%" + data.search + "%' AND " : "");

//app filters values
result = result.replace(/@fields@/g,fields);

//build search column
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you narrow down your problem, help could come much quicker.

Comment: My problem is that I can't figure out how to reach the desired result that I've written in the begging of my question: replace this part of the string @ndos@ by the variable that as the same name between the two @

Comment: Well, that part is easy: `.replace(/@(\w+)@/g, function(m,g1) {return data[g1]; })`

Comment: I'm getting all the properties of 'data' object from a http request, so this isn't a local variable, so I don't know the value between the two @, only know the default ones (filtes,search,field)

Comment: Thanks, but that's only works if the 'g1' it's an 'data' property, it's possible to get as an variable (ndos and nmdos)?

Comment: Use a hash table like `var obj = { ndos: '615', nmdos = 'Orders'};` and get those values the way I suggested. Just check if these key-value pairs exist before accessing them.

Comment: In order to get the variable value, I've changed your function to: function(m,g1) {return eval(g1); }

Comment: Using `eval` is repeatedly stated to be not a good idea. Are you sure it is the best approach in your case?

Comment: You're right, I'll create an object to store all the data to be replaced, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial thought is something like this.

```js
var myMap = { 'ndos': '615', 'nmdos': 'Orders' };
var keys = [];
var str = "SELECT name, age, address , (name || age || address) AS search FROM users WHERE search LIKE '%lisboa%' AND name LIKE '%ricardo%' AND age LIKE '%23%' AND ndos = @ndos@ AND nmdos = '@nmdos@' AND 1 = 1";
for (var key in myMap) {
  if (myMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   str = str.replace('@' +key + '@', myMap[key])
  }
}
 document.writeln(str);
```

Where you store those variables in an associative array and then use that to replace in the string.

Comment: Thanks, it's an alternative for the comments of Wiktor Stribiżew in my question, either way, I prefer the Wiktor Stribiżew method just because, instead of iterate trough the myMap properties, I'm replacing all @example@, if doesn't exist, I replace with a black space